# How to pass multi column to remove filter using All in Dax formula in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have one requirement where I need to overwrite the filter context using All key word in Power bi Dax

In the table there are two value columns: Sales and Purchase and one date column .My calculation is based on these column

Simply dividing  Sales by Purchase .But there are many attributes column with text values I want to remove the filter context for Purchase  calculation .My data will look like below

[image]

My Dax formula looks like this:

```
measure_name =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( table_name[Sales] ),
    YEAR ( table_name[Date of entry] ) = MAX ( YEAR ( table_name[Date of entry] ) )
)
    / CALCULATE (
        SUM ( table_name[Purchase] ),
        YEAR ( table_name[Date of entry] ) = MAX ( YEAR ( table_name[Date of entry] ) ),
        ALL ( table_name[Attribute1] ),
        ALL ( table_name[Attribute2] ),
        ALL ( table_name[Attribute3] )
    )
```

here I have put all attributes in the dax simply putting coma which will throw error

Any one can help me how to write this .Only for purchase(denominator calculation ) I want to remove the filter for any number of attribute columns.Or is there any other way to do this calculation .This data is dummy data   .In future if we are getting more attributes , can we pass one list for this All parameters .So that user will just update in the excel all attributes and when it get refreshed , these parameter values to pass in to this All parameter automatically..?

Comment: You got the error because you missed closing parentheses ) several times.

Comment: In future if we are getting more attributes , can we pass one list for this All parameters .So  that user will just update  in the excel all attributes    and when it get refreshed , these parameter values to pass in to this All  parameter automatically..?.

Comment: What is the meaning of these attributes? Can you give an example?

Comment: Attributes are column names.In future the table will have more columns which need to exclude using All

Comment: I understand that these are column names. But what do they mean? Please give an example.

Comment: Each column has its own data..like smoking habit yes or not , marriage status, country etc

Comment: some cells in the column are blank as well as

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251380/discussion-between-faisal-thayyil-and-rado).